# Appropriate SQL server index for "insert only" schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

We are using SQLServer 2008, and have an "insert-only" schema for many tables.

An example of the sort of table that we have is (and this is just one example):

```
create table spotquotes
(
   Id numeric(19,0) identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered,
   feeditem_id numeric(19,0) not null,
   value_ask float not null,
   value_bid float not null,
   effectiveDateUTC datetime not null default getutcdate()
)
```

We then query the table with this query

```
select * from spotquotes q
inner join
    (select feeditem_id, max(id) as latest from spotquotes group by feeditem_id) q2
    on q.id = q2.latest and q.feeditem_id = q2.feeditem_id
```

In fact, it makes sense to create a view of the above query:

```
create view latestspotquotes as
select * from spotquotes q
inner join
    (select feeditem_id, max(id) as latest from spotquotes group by feeditem_id) q2
    on q.id = q2.latest and q.feeditem_id = q2.feeditem_id
```

i.e. we want the "latest" insert into the table for each feeditem_id -but we also have the ability to query the state of the table as it was at any time in the past (which is very nice for audit considerations).

An even simpler way to put it. I wish to optimize the following query:

```
select feeditem_id, max(id) as latest from spotquotes group by feeditem_id
```

This table typically has hundreds of millions of rows - but a small number of feeditem_id instances which are very likely to be at the end of the table.

With the existing primary key and about 100 million rows in this table,
SQLServer 2008 takes 6 seconds to execute this query - it's very slow.

So I'm wondering - if we were to create an index for this table to speed up this query, what index should we create?

Sadly, management studio does not suggest an index for us.

EDIT: There are still issues but I will raise as a separate question.

**UPDATE**

A much faster query (< 10 ms) can be coaxed out of SQL server by using "cross apply" in conjunction with a select top * ... order by Id desc. See [Convincing SQL server to search backwards on clustered index for an insert only schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992463/convincing-sql-server-to-search-backwards-on-clustered-index-for-an-insert-only) for details.

Comment: `(select feeditem_id, max(id) as latest as id)` -- are you sure this is right?

Comment: Your nested query is on the same table or a different table?

Comment: raholling - it's the same table.

Comment: dean, raholling - have correct the SQL. The question might make more sense now!

Comment: Sorry if I am a bit confused, but if you id is your primary key wouldn't you expect there to be only one result for each feeditem_id?   I would think that you could then just use your max(id) and the additional column information that you need.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: raholling yes that is right - there should be exactly one result per feeditem_id - the latest spot quote for each "feeditem_id" (feeditem_id is the primary key that links to the ticker symbol in a 'feeditem' table).

Comment: Another way to put it: if this was *not* insert only and we updated the table, feeditem_id would be a key field.

Comment: @raholling - I insert a record for `feeditem_id = 1` and then later insert another record for `feeditem_id = 1`.  Now that `feeditem_id` has two records, each with a different `id`.  The record with the highest `id` is the most current one, and the other is the historic value.  It's `INSERT Only` because this insert operation has done what an `UPDATE` would normally do, but also preserved the old record for audit tracking, etc.  Thus the query in the view is implementing the `return only the most recent state for each 'feeditem_id'` business logic.

Comment: @MatBailie you have it exactly right

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks. Before his edit I just wanted to make sure that I was not missing something.  I have a much clearer understanding now.  Thank you.

Comment: ok so now you all understand my question, can anyone give me a good answer? I am not a database expert... but I am sure there must be a way of doing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
select feeditem_id, max(id) as latest from spotquotes group by feeditem_id
```

create the following nonclustered index

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Spotquotes_feeditem_id on spotquotes(feeditem, id)
```

Comment: Thanks very much dean - I'll try this now. Small typo should be spotquotes(feeditem_id, id)

Comment: Sadly, although the showplan_xml shows it is now using this index, it *still* takes 5 seconds!

Comment: If it's ordered index scan, that's it. Are you selecting any other columns beyond these two?

Comment: Does it matter if I have "id asc" vs "id desc"?

Comment: It shouldn't in this case.

Comment: If I filter out those feed items that have not been updated in a while, it is reasonably fast. But the index appears to have made no difference to the query time based on "set statistics time on".

Comment: CPU time = 11372 ms,  elapsed time = 780 ms. both with and without the index once I restrict it to the 10 most recently updated ids). It should be much faster...

Comment: Actually dean I discovered there is another index which is why the other query isn't any slower. I will accept your answer it seems to be the "canonical" right answer.

Comment: But... it's disappointing. A simple linear search along the spotquotes table from the end walking backwards would be much more efficient. I don't see why it isn't possible to instruct SQL server to do this.

Comment: For this particular query it's as good as it gets. It could probably be written more efficiently, but for that we'll need access to statistics information on distribution and cardinality of your data. But now it's still pretty ok; it's not scanning the table, but the NC index in an ordered fashion. For a single feeditem_id it should return instantenously.

Comment: Hi dean - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992463/convincing-sql-server-to-search-backwards-on-clustered-index-for-an-insert-only which got to the crux of my issue.

Comment: Sure, we have options if you would rewrite the query. But you were explicit that you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Insert only Index :S I thin insert only schemas are best left without any indexes but having any index on a table will hurt the performance of your insert operations.

What about creating an index on `feeditem_id` and `effectiveDateUTC` fields something like

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX_feeditem_id_effectiveDateUTC
ON dbo.spotquotes(feeditem_id ASC, effectiveDateUTC DESC)
GO
```

and now write your query something like .....

```
;WITH LastestRecords
 AS(
   SELECT Id 
        ,feeditem_id 
        ,value_ask
        ,value_bid
        ,effectiveDateUTC
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY feeditem_id ORDER BY ffectiveDateUTC DESC) AS RN
  FROM spotquotes
  )
 SELECT Id 
        ,feeditem_id 
        ,value_ask
        ,value_bid
        ,effectiveDateUTC
 FROM LastestRecords
 WHERE RN = 1
```

**OR**

Create an index as follows

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX_feeditem_id_Id
ON dbo.spotquotes(feeditem_id ASC, ID DESC)
GO
```

**Query**

```
;WITH LastestRecords
 AS(
   SELECT Id 
        ,feeditem_id 
        ,value_ask
        ,value_bid
        ,effectiveDateUTC
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY feeditem_id ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RN
  FROM spotquotes
  )
 SELECT Id 
        ,feeditem_id 
        ,value_ask
        ,value_bid
        ,effectiveDateUTC
 FROM LastestRecords
 WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: `INSERT Only` refers to the fact that you don't do `UPDATE` operations.  Instead you insert a new record, keeping the old record(s), and use business logic to determine which of these records to select from *(which are 'currently effective')*.

Comment: Right. Just to add - properly indexing `ROW_NUMBER()` means creating a compound index on `(partitioning_columns, order_by_columns)`, perhaps including columns for even better performance and maybe filtering it if there's a static WHERE clause.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this works - but I want an answer which achieves the correct query plan *without* having to change the SQL query... that should be possible shouldn't it?

Comment: Also... I am using max(ID), not max(effectiveDateUTC)... why is effectiveDateUTC part of the index?

Comment: Well the query will return exactly what you are looking for, doing this way you will avoid the inefficient join on a non-indexed column (i.e feeditem_id) which can be a real performance killer and also GROUP BY and the use of Aggregate function. 
Have you actually compared the execution plans of both queries ???

Comment: I don't understand how the query works so I cannot correct things like  the typos. For example, what is "CTE"? And why reference effectiveDateUTC?

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. M Ali's query took 20 seconds after which I terminated it. I don't know what it is doing but it is certainly not faster.

Comment: Cheers @a_horse_with_no_name :) damn typos

Comment: @PaulHollingsworth Try the new query along with the index I have proposed, I am pretty darn sure it will be much fater then a join on non-indexed column.

Comment: Hi M. ALi. I've tried your updated query but it is still taking well over 60 seconds (it still has not finished) - much worse than the simple group by query.