# Convincing SQL server to search backwards on clustered index for an insert only schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our database has many tables which follow an "insert only" schema. Rows are added to the end, the "current" value can then be found by finding the most recently inserted row for each logical key.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SPOTQUOTE](
[ID] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
[QUOTETYPE] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[QUOTED_UTC_TS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[QUOTED_UTC_MILLIS] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[RECEIVED_UTC_TS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[RECEIVED_UTC_MILLIS] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[VALUE_ASK] [float] NULL,
[VALUE_BID] [float] NULL,
[FEEDITEM_ID] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
[SAMPLING] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [SPOTQUOTE_pk1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,            ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The logical key of this table is "feeditem_id". However, so that we can perform historical queries, instead, rows are only ever inserted into this table at the end, using "ID" as the actual physical key.

Therefore, we know that the max(id) for each distinct feeditem_id is going to be found towards the end of the table, not the beginning.

When querying the table, we want to find the "latest" update for each "feeditem_id", which is the "logical key" for this table.

The following is the query we want:

```
select feeditem_id, max(id)
from spotquote
group by feeditem_id
having feeditem_id in (827, 815, 806)
```

so that we have the latest id for each feeditem_id.

Unfortunately, SQL server 2008 generates a sub optimal query plan for this query.

From my understanding of SQL, the fact that this is selecting for the max id, which is the primary clustered key, implies that the optimal query plan for this is to:

- Start at the end of the table
- Walk backwards, keeping track of the max id encountered so far for each feeditem_id
- Stop once an Id for each feeditem_id has been found

I would expect this to be extremely fast.

First question: is there some way I can explicitly tell SQL server to execute the above query plan?

I have tried:

```
SELECT feeditem_id, max(ID) as latest from SPOTQUOTE with (index(SPOTQUOTE_pk1)) group by feeditem_id
having FEEDITEM_ID in (827, 815, 806)
```

But, in practise, it seems to execute even more slowly.

I am wondering if the "clustered index scan" is walking the table forwards instead of backwards... Is there a way I can confirm if this is what is happening?

How can I confirm that this clustered index scan works from the back of the table, and how can I convince SQL server to search the clustered index backwards instead?

**Update**

The issue is indeed that the clustered index scan is not searching backwards when I perform a group by.

In contrast, the following SQL query produces essentially the correct query plan:

```
select
FEEDITEM_ID, MAX(id) from
(select top 100 * from
SPOTQUOTE
where FEEDITEM_ID in (827,815,806)
order by ID desc) s
group by feeditem_id
```

I can see it in management studio that "Ordered = True" and "Scan Direction = BACKWARD":

[image: Screenshot from Management Studio]

and it executes blindingly fast - 2 milliseconds - and it "almost certainly" works.

I just want it to "stop" once it has found an entry for each feed id rather than the first 100 entries.

It's frustrating that there seems to be no way to tell SQL server to execute this obviously more efficient query.

If I do a normal "group by" with appropriate indexes on feeditem_id and id, it's faster - about 300 ms - but still that's still 100 times slower than the backwards clustered index scan.

[image: A normal group by with appropriate index defined achieves 300 ms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is unable to produce such a query plan as of 2012. Rewrite the query:

```
SELECT ids.feeditem_id, MaxID
FROM (VALUES (827), (815), (806)) ids(feeditem_id)
CROSS APPLY (
 select TOP 1 ID AS MaxID
 from spotquote sq
 where sq.feeditem_id = ids.feeditem_id
 ORDER BY ID DESC
) x
```

This results in a plan that does a seek into the `spotquote` table per ID that you specify. This is the best we can do. SQL Server is unable to abort an aggregation as soon as all groups you are interested in have at least one value.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the disappointing news. I do not quite understand what your query does I will have to look up "CROSS APPLY" but your query is indeed much faster than the original.

Comment: You can also use a join. CROSS APPLY seems needlessly complicated at second thought.

Comment: The funny thing is that set statistics time on
select top 20 *
from SPOTQUOTE
where feeditem_id in (827, 815, 806)
order by id desc
set statistics time off executes ridiculously quickly (1 ms) and is almost certainly going to have all of the information required...

Comment: No, it does not because you only query the top 20 rows. In the query plan you get for this particular query you are not guaranteed to have the maximum rows included. You'd have to remove the "top 20" and then it will be slow again.

Comment: Yes no I am aware of the issue. It's just so frustrating to be so close... yet so far. I suppose I can write a stupid inelegant "loop" to select each feed item in turn... There are generally only going to about about 20 of them.

Comment: Don't make the mistake of actually writing a loop for this. SQL Server does this loop for you as part of the query plan. Just to clarify: Does this solution work for you? Any issues unsolved?

Comment: it works faster but it's still not very fast - the "top" query for each feed item id executes in less than a ms. Whereas the cross apply seems much slower. Can you show me what the "join" syntax looks like?

Comment: The cross apply takes 5 seconds for those three ids. A "top 20" spot quote which ended up returning entries for each of the relevant ids executed in 1 millisecond.

Comment: So at this point, ugly as a loop is, I think it in confunction with select top 1 * would be much much faster. So.. I have to concluded that the cross apply is still not searching 'backwards' through the clustered index.

Comment: Please post an image of the execution plan for the cross apply query. You have indexed `sq.feeditem_id, id`, right? This is required for a fast seek.

Comment: How/where do I post an image?

Comment: Edit your post or use some image hosting service.

Comment: The table has 100 million rows - I want the 2 millisecond query time which you get from it doing the backwards seek on the clustered index. There is an index on feeditem_id, id but that only brings the query down to about 700 ms (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989107/appropriate-sql-server-index-for-insert-only-schema)

Comment: Just to confirm: with index on feeditem_id, id, I get: CPU time = 1778 ms,  elapsed time = 1784 ms for the cross apply query

Comment: In contrast, with select
FEEDITEM_ID, MAX(id) from
(select top 100 * from
SPOTQUOTE
where FEEDITEM_ID in (827,815,806)
order by ID desc) s
group by feeditem_id I get CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.

Comment: At this point I need to look at the plan because it will show the problem. 2ms query times are clearly attainable in this case.

Comment: OK I have added a screenshot.

Comment: it's true that in the "worst case" the clustered index scan might actually be very poor, if one of the feed item ids has not been updated in a while. But in practise, it's always going to be pretty fast.

Comment: Ok, the query optimizer has a weakness here that I did not know about. I was unable to convert the group-by max into a TOP 1. I did that manually now. Please try the updated query. If it still is not blindingly fast, please post the new plan.

Comment: Actually the plain "group by" query does better than the cross apply. But it's still 300 ms instead of 3 ms. I attached the screenshot for that query plan too.

Comment: "usr" - your revised plan is blindingly fast!!!!    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.